# How to flatten Array of WrappedArray of structs in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_list(typeCounts): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

Example data:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id         |collect_list(typeCounts)                                                    |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1          |[WrappedArray([B00XGS,6], [B001FY,5]), WrappedArray([B06LJ7,4])]|
|2          |[WrappedArray([B00UFY,3])]                                              |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I flatten `collect_list(typeCounts)` to a flat array of structs in **scala**? I have read some answers on stackoverflow for similar questions suggesting UDF's, but I am not sure what the UDF method signature should be for structs.

Comment: spark version ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Spark `2.4`+, instead of using a UDF (which is generally less efficient than native Spark functions) you can apply [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@flatten(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), like below:

```
df.withColumn("collect_list(typeCounts)", flatten($"collect_list(typeCounts)"))
```

---

> i am not sure what the udf method signature should be for structs

UDF takes `structs` as `Rows` for input and may return them as Scala case classes.  To flatten the nested collections, you can create a simple UDF as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class TC(`type`: String, count: Long)

val flattenLists = udf{ (lists: Seq[Seq[Row]]) =>
  lists.flatMap( _.map{ case Row(t: String, c: Long) => TC(t, c) } )
}
```

To test out the UDF, let's assemble a DataFrame with your described schema:

```
val df = Seq(
    ("1", Seq(TC("B00XGS", 6), TC("B001FY", 5))),
    ("1", Seq(TC("B06LJ7", 4))),
    ("2", Seq(TC("B00UFY", 3)))
  ).toDF("id", "typeCounts").
  groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("typeCounts"))

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- collect_list(typeCounts): array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

Applying the UDF:

```
df.
  withColumn("collect_list(typeCounts)", flattenLists($"collect_list(typeCounts)")).
  printSchema
// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- collect_list(typeCounts): array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```